# ICU's collator assumes that "a" and "ą" are the same

Tags: internationalization, collation, icu

I'm using ICU with Lithuanian (`lt_LT`) language. The alphabet for this language is the following: `a ą b c č d e ę ė <...> v z ž`

However, when sorting, ICU's collator assumes that, for example, `a` and `ą` (`a` with ogonek) are equivalent, so a list of Lithuanian words get sorted as this:

```
a, ą, ab, aba, abadas, <...>, b, ba, <...>`
```

When the expected result would be:

```
a, ab, aba, abadas, <...>, ą, <...>, b, ba, <...>
```

The same happens with other "accented" letters (`e` - `ę` - `ė`, `z` - `ž`, etc.)

More specific test case: running `source/samples/coll/coll -locale lt_LT -source ą -target aa` decides that `source is less than target` when it's not the case (see [coll.cpp](https://github.com/ctapmex/icu-c/blob/master/source/samples/coll/coll.cpp) if you need to).

Is this behavior expected? Is this a bug or a feature? If so, how can I prevent ICU's collator from aligning "similar" letters together?

Comment: You'd do better to ask the ICU lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letters are listed as a secondary difference in the CLDR tailorings and so they will sort [like so](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=lt&d_=en&x=col&str=a%0Daba%0Dba%0D%5Cu0105%0Dabadas%0Db%0Dab). If this is wrong, bring it up to [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org), not an ICU problem.  [Mimer](http://developer.mimer.com/charts/lithuanian.htm) agrees.